# Go to another method from a boolean method

Tags: java

guys, I'm programming the Gomoku game in Java and I am a little bit stuck with a stupid problem. I want the player to be able to block a field so I made two methods, both of them boolean:

DoYouWishToBlockAField and BlockingField. I want to make it so that when the first one is true, I go to the second, and when it's false, of course, break the operation and don't block any field. Can you help me please ?

```
    public static void DoYouWishToBlockAField(){
   if(true){
       BlockingField();
   } else (false);
```

Here i get the error message and I've been wondering how to make it right.

}

```
   public static void BlockingField(int theSeed) {
      boolean validInput = false;  // for input validation
      do {
         if (theSeed == BlockedField1) {
            System.out.print("Player 1: Block a Field: ");
         } else{
            System.out.print("Player 2: Block a Field: ");
         }
         int row = in.nextInt() - 1;  // array index starts at 0 instead of 1
         int col = in.nextInt() - 1;
         if (row >= 0 && row < ROWS && col >= 0 && col < COLS && board[row][col] == Empty) {
            currentRow = row;
            currentCol = col;
            board[currentRow][currentCol] = theSeed;  // update game-board content
            validInput = true;  // input okay, exit loop
         } else {
            System.out.println("The cell at (" + (row + 1) + "," + (col + 1)
                  + ") is taken. Try another move.");
         }
      } while (!validInput);  // repeat until input is valid
   }
```

Comment: `if(true){
       BlockingField();
   } else (false);` what is this?

Comment: Just an incorrect sample. I tried it, but of course it didn't work. I want the program to use the method BlockingAField(). if the method DoYouWishToBlockAField is true.

Comment: Do you have method `BlockingField()` I mean same method but without params.

Comment: please you should follow coding guidelines while posting questions. otherwise it makes looking at code so mch difficult

Comment: sorry, i'm kinda new at this

Comment: please make an edit and post a code that compiles. take in to consideration answer of @ManishNagar. Also do not include the logic that is not related to your question

Comment: @PeterGeorgiev I understand what you want to achieve. But If you show us your complete code then it will be easy to give you correct solution.

Comment: @smit would you please make an edit to include the crux cz I am nt able to get it :(

Comment: @NarendraPathai `crux cz`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @smit i meant what is the question exactly trying to ask.

Comment: @NarendraPathai OP wanted to call another method from another method if that method is boolean. I still don't know what he exactly wants so I put option to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

use parameter name when function calling

```
BlockingField(parameterName);
```